# Mysql query with left join - specialize index if two rows are the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, left-join

I have a table called `users` and another called `grouppost` in my mysql database. Both tables have the `id` row in common. So when I make an sql query left joining the two tables how can I decide which `id` row I want?
**Example**

```
$sql = "SELECT gp.*, u.*
      FROM grouppost
      AS gp LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = gp.author
      WHERE gp.gname = ? AND gp.type = ? ORDER BY gp.pdate DESC $limit";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param("ss",$g,$zero);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result_new = $stmt->get_result();
      if ($result_new->num_rows > 0){
         while ($row = $result_new->fetch_assoc()) {
            $grouppost_id = $row["id"]; // I want to get the id from table grouppost but I get the id from the users table
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target it separately in the result set, you can alias it in your select:

```
SELECT gp.*, u.*, gp.id AS grouppost_id 
FROM grouppost AS gp 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = gp.author
WHERE gp.gname = ? 
  AND gp.type = ? 
ORDER BY gp.pdate DESC
$limit
```

Comment: But when I run the query it gives back the same (`id` in `users` table). The sql is OK, the problem will be how I save the datas in the while loop. I need to specialize the index of `row`.

Comment: That's why I added the `gp.id AS grouppost_id` to the query. If you want the grouppost_id, it is now under a different name so it does not conflict with the other value.

Comment: Oh so you mean `$row["grouppost_id"]`. Worked!